# Error in adding library

Tags: android, android-studio

I've researched on how to add libraries that I have downloaded in GitHub.

This is the file that I downloaded in GitHub (in .zip format): https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

This is the tutorial that I watched:
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk"

The error that displays in my Android Studio when syncing the gradle build.

> Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile'
>   to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for
>   project :Libraries:android-maps-utils-master.

Comment: post your build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to download it. It's on Maven Central. Add it as a dependency to your `build.gradle` file e.g.

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```

Comment: can you still run it if offline? Because my internet is not consistent

Comment: @YaZaoRuZakiaga Once downloaded it would not re-download it.

Comment: not all (is not almost none) github libraries are hosted on maven central.